# No adapter attached; skipping layout when I try to fetch an image from the Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat app project where everything works fine but when I try to send an image the logcat shows me the error **No adapter attached; skipping layout**. In my MessageChatactivity, the image which I store it in firebase storage when a user sends an image is not getting fetched from the DB but the text messages works fine. In the database, if its a text message them I am assigning the DB child Url with null,
if its an image I am assigning the same with the image directory which I store it in Firebase storage.

thanks in advance!!

**MessageChatactivity:**

```
package com.example.whatsapp

class MessageChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // userIdVisit is the receiver user id
    var userIdVisit: String=""
    var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? =null
    var chatsAdapter: ChatsAdapter? = null
    // Chat folder contains all the messages with the id stored in the DB.
    var mChatList : List<Chat>? = null
    private lateinit var recycler_view_chats: RecyclerView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_chat)

        intent=intent
        // to get both the sender id and the receiver id
        // visit is defined in UserAdapter
        userIdVisit = intent.getStringExtra("visit_id")
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        // to access the recycler view to put all the messages we stored in mChatList
        recycler_view_chats = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_chats)
        recycler_view_chats.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
        recycler_view_chats.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        // to fetch the receiver name and profile pic
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            .child("Users").child(userIdVisit)
        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                // to get the dp of the receiver
                val user : Users? = p0.getValue(Users::class.java)
                username_mchat.text= user!!.getUserName()
                Picasso.get().load(user.getProfile()).into(profile_image_mchat)

                retrieveMessages(firebaseUser!!.uid,userIdVisit, user.getProfile())
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)
            {

            }
        })

        send_message_bt.setOnClickListener {

            val message = text_message.text.toString()
            if (message=="")
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@MessageChatActivity, "Please enter some message...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else
            {
                sendMessageToUser(firebaseUser!!.uid,userIdVisit,message)
            }
            // to make the text_message edittext null once we send a text
            text_message.setText("")

        }

        attach_image_file_btn.setOnClickListener {
            // to send the user to mobile phone gallery
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            intent.type = "image/*"
            // to get the image from gallery
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Pick an image"),438)



        }
    }

    private fun sendMessageToUser(senderId: String, receiverId: String?, message: String)
    {
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        // have to create unique key for each message
        val messageKey = reference.push().key
        //to create a hash map
        val messageHashMap = HashMap<String,Any?>()
        messageHashMap["sender"] = senderId
        messageHashMap["message"] = message
        messageHashMap["receiver"] = receiverId
        messageHashMap["isseen"] = false
        messageHashMap["url"] = ""
        messageHashMap["messageId"] = messageKey
        // this creates a Chat folder in DB and places all the child of messageHashMap under it
        reference.child("Chats")
            .child(messageKey!!)
            .setValue(messageHashMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                // to add the chats to Chats fragment for both sender and the receiver
                if(task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    // this is to retrieve the last message for each user (unread message)
                    // for sender add the receiver to his chat fragment
                    val chatListReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .reference
                        .child("ChatList")
                        .child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
                        .child(userIdVisit)
                    chatListReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                            if (!p0.exists())
                            {
                                chatListReference.child("id").setValue(userIdVisit)
                            }

                            // for receiver add the sender to his chat fragment
                            val chatListReceiverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                .reference
                                .child("ChatList")
                                .child(userIdVisit)
                                .child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
                            chatListReceiverRef.child("id").setValue(firebaseUser!!.uid)

                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                        }
                    })

                    // to implement the push notifications
                    val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                        .child("Users").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)

                }
            }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode==438 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null && data!!.data!=null)
        {
            // to display a loading bar
            val progressBar = ProgressDialog(this)
            progressBar.setMessage("sending image...")
            progressBar.show()

            val fileUri = data.data
            // to send the image to a folder Chat Images in DB so that it can be send to the receiver
            val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Chat Images")
            val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            //unique id for each image like we did for text
            val messageId = ref.push().key
            val filePath = storageReference.child("$messageId.jpg")

            var uploadTask : StorageTask<*>
            uploadTask = filePath.putFile(fileUri!!)
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot,Task<Uri>> {task ->
                // not
                if (!task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    task.exception?.let {
                        throw it
                    }
                }
                return@Continuation filePath.downloadUrl
            }).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    val downloadUrl = task.result
                    val url = downloadUrl.toString()

                    val messageHashMap = HashMap<String,Any?>()
                    messageHashMap["sender"] = firebaseUser!!.uid
                    messageHashMap["message"] = "sent you an image."
                    messageHashMap["receiver"] = userIdVisit
                    messageHashMap["isseen"] = false
                    messageHashMap["url"] = url
                    messageHashMap["messageId"] = messageId
                    // all the above are Chats folder children in DB
                    ref.child("Chats").child(messageId!!).setValue(messageHashMap)
                    progressBar.dismiss()
                    // these info's are fetched using the Chat model class

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun retrieveMessages(senderId: String, receiverId: String?, receiverImageUrl: String?)
    {
        // to store all the messages in mChatlist
        mChatList = ArrayList()
        // to retrieve all the messages under Chats folder in DB
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            .child("Chats")

         reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
             override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
             {
                 (mChatList as ArrayList<Chat>).clear()
                 for(snapshot in p0.children)
                 {
                    val chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat::class.java)
                     if (chat!!.getReceiver().equals(senderId) && chat.getSender().equals(receiverId)
                         || chat.getReceiver().equals(receiverId)  && chat.getSender().equals(senderId)
                     )
                     {
                         (mChatList as ArrayList<Chat>).add(chat)
                     }
                     chatsAdapter = ChatsAdapter(this@MessageChatActivity,  (mChatList as ArrayList<Chat>), receiverImageUrl!!)
                     // after this we have to display the messages in the recycler view on activity_message_chat
                     recycler_view_chats.adapter = chatsAdapter
                 }
             }

             override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

             }
         })
    }
}
```

this is my adapter class
**ChatsAdapter:**

```
package com.example.whatsapp.AdapterClasses

class ChatsAdapter(
    mContext: Context,
    mChatList: List<Chat>,
    imageUrl: String
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatsAdapter.ViewHolder?>()
{

    private val mContext: Context
    private val mChatList: List<Chat>
    private val imageUrl: String
    var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!

    init {
        this.mContext = mContext
        this.mChatList = mChatList
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): ViewHolder
    {
        // message_item_left  position == 0
        // message_item_Right  position == 1
        return if (position == 1){
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(com.example.whatsapp.R.layout.message_item_right,parent,false)
            ViewHolder(view)
        }else
        {
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(com.example.whatsapp.R.layout.message_item_left,parent,false)
            ViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        //!!  added coz of error
        return mChatList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        var profile_image: CircleImageView?= null
        var show_text_message: TextView?=null
        var left_image_view: ImageView?=null
        var text_seen: TextView?=null
        var right_image_view: ImageView?=null

        init
        {
            profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)
            show_text_message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_text_message)
            left_image_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.left_image_view)
            text_seen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_seen)
            right_image_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.right_image_view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
    {
        val chat : Chat = mChatList[position]

        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.profile_image)
        //condition to check is a message is a text or image
        //image messages
        if (chat.getMessage().equals("sent you an image.") || !chat.getUrl().equals(""))
        {
            // image message - right side
            // .equals() changed to ==
            if (chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser!!.uid))
            {
                holder.show_text_message!!.visibility == View.GONE
                holder.right_image_view!!.visibility == View.VISIBLE
                Picasso.get().load(chat.getUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.profie).into(holder.right_image_view)
            }else
            // image message - left side
            // !.equals() changed to !=
                if (!chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser!!.uid))
                {
                    holder.show_text_message!!.visibility == View.GONE
                    holder.left_image_view!!.visibility == View.VISIBLE
                    Picasso.get().load(chat.getUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.profie).into(holder.left_image_view)
                }
        }else
        //text messages
        {
            holder.show_text_message!!.text = chat.getMessage()

        }
        // sent and seen message
        if(position.equals(mChatList.size-1))
        {
            if (chat.isIsSeen())
            {
                holder.text_seen!!.text = "Seen"
                if (chat.getMessage().equals("sent you an image.") && !chat.getUrl().equals(""))
                {
                    // to move the seen text to bottom of the image
                    val lp: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams? = holder.text_seen!!.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams?
                    lp!!.setMargins(0,245, 10, 0 )
                    holder.text_seen!!.layoutParams = lp
                }
            }else
            {
                holder.text_seen!!.text = "Sent"
                if (chat.getMessage().equals("sent you an image.") && !chat.getUrl().equals(""))
                {
                    // to move the seen text to bottom of the image
                    val lp: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams? = holder.text_seen!!.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams?
                    lp!!.setMargins(0,245, 10, 0 )
                    holder.text_seen!!.layoutParams = lp
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            holder.text_seen!!.visibility = View.GONE
        }


    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int
    {



        return if (mChatList[position].getSender().equals(firebaseUser!!.uid))
        {
            // refer onCreateViewHolder method
            // sender = userid then update in message_item_right
            1
        }else
        {
            //else then update in message_item_right(receiver)
            0
        }
    }
}

**logcat:**

2020-07-11 12:53:48.824 12690-12690/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-07-11 12:53:48.825 12690-12690/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-07-11 12:53:48.850 12690-12690/? E/xample.whatsap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-07-11 12:54:03.293 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() rootView is null
2020-07-11 12:54:07.139 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-07-11 12:54:27.814 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() rootView is null
2020-07-11 12:54:32.991 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-07-11 12:54:42.950 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-07-11 12:54:42.985 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-07-11 12:54:43.717 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView returned.
2020-07-11 12:54:43.830 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-07-11 12:54:43.866 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-07-11 12:55:07.741 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() rootView is null
2020-07-11 12:55:09.620 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-07-11 12:55:11.837 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-07-11 12:55:11.868 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-07-11 12:55:12.722 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView returned.
2020-07-11 12:55:12.814 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-07-11 12:55:12.863 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-07-11 12:55:34.379 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null
2020-07-11 12:55:38.764 12690-12690/com.example.whatsapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView returned.
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **more than 600 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

In your OnCreate() initialize and set the adapter

```
recycler_view_chats.adapter = chatsAdapter
```

and when the list changes call

```
chatsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```